# How can I log out of Trello and log back into Trello?

Tags: trello, login, logout

I am sharing a computer with a co-worker.  We have two different Trello accounts and we're using the same browser.  I need to log out of Trello so I can log into my own account.

Answer (score 2):

To logout, click your profile icon at the top right and select "Log Out"

Note: this will log out of all Trello sessions in the browser, so you and your coworker can't be logged in at the same time unless you are using 2 browsers or are browsing incognito.

Answer (score 1):

You could install another browser (e.g. Firefox or Google Chrome) and use that one to view your Trello-account, your co-worker can use the other browser with his account.

Answer (score 0):

Another option (that doesn't involve installing another browser) might be to have one of you use your browser's regular session, and the other open a "Private Browsing" session in a new window to log into Trello. This way you can both stay logged into Trello at the same time (if that matters).

- [Chrome Incognito Mode](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95464)
- [Firefox Private Browsing](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/private-browsing-browse-web-without-saving-info)
- [Internet Explorer InPrivate Browsing](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie-9/features/in-private)